# My LoginPage needs validate the UserId & Password with the Stored data in Excel sheet?

Tags: .net, excel, authentication, c#-3.0, oledbconnection

I’m developing a Login Page for my C# application. Here I am using Excel sheet to store the user credentials.

- Here, what I have to do is, when an user gives his credentials and clicks Login button:

  1. Load the “USERIDS” Excel sheet into the DataTable’s Object.
  2. Now check the User Id which is given the “tbuserid” textbox with “USER_ID” column of the “USERIDS” table.
  3. If the User Id is matched, then check with the corresponding matched record’s “PASSWORD” field, [i.e., not entire PASSWORD field needs to check]
     *Note: If the User Id is not matched, then no need to check the password field. And show the alert message with the “ErrorProvider” control*
  4. If the User Id & Password both are matched, then close this login form & open the “Form1” Form.
- The Password field Textbox should be visible with the ‘*’ character.
- Problem: I have getting error message when i clicking the Login button after the credentials are given.

BTW, the following Connection string statement is used:

```
con1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=D:\\USERIDS.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;IMEX=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

To use excel in C#:
use the Interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

ie:

```
//Added Namespaces
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;


    private Object[,] generateExcel()
    {
        //Open excel file
        Excel.Application objApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbooks objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
        Excel._Workbook objBook = objBooks.Open("YourPathHere", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        Excel.Sheets objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
        Excel._Worksheet objSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);
        objApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        //Opens excel - remove this line for end product
        objApp.Visible = true;

        //Data portion
        //Your range as the arguement
        Excel.Range objRange = (Excel.Range)objSheet.get_Range("A6", "D6");

        //Create table
        Object[,] tableData = (Object[,])objRange.Value2;

        //Close excel - add this in end product
        objApp.Application.Quit();

        return tableData;
    }
```

This returns an object array of all the Excel data.
At which point you just go:
table[x,y].ToString();

Now you have a string to compare you login against!
Good luck!